# Migration from Tomcat7 to Jetty (Catalina.base)

Tags: java, tomcat, jetty

I'm migrating from Tomcat7 to Jetty(9.3). And in some part in my code I have this:

```
final List<File> files = FileFinder.getFilesMatching(System.getProperty("catalina.base"), "^(special-prefix).*$");
```

So I want to replace the string "catalina.base" for something similar in Jetty.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Jetty you have the following environment variables, similar to tomcat:

> **Jetty Base**
>   Also known as the `${jetty.base}` property.
>   This is the location for your configurations and customizations to the Jetty
>   distribution.
>
> **Jetty Home**
>   Also known as the `${jetty.home}` property.
>   This is the location for the Jetty distribution binaries, default XML IoC
>   configurations, and default module definitions.

Eg.

```
final List<File> files = FileFinder.getFilesMatching(System.getProperty("jetty.base"), "^(special-prefix).*$")
```

See also: [Managing Jetty Base and Jetty Home](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup-base-and-home.html)

Comment: When I try to get this properties It always return null, I print a list of variables but they didn't appear.

Comment: @FedericoAlvarez How do you start the server? runs jetty.sh?

Comment: No, I run on eclipse.

Comment: @FedericoAlvarez Do you use some plugin? or is called start.jar?

Comment: I'm only doing right click and then: Start Java Aplication

Comment: Ok, Do you are using in this way `System.getProperty ("jetty.base}")`?

Comment: Just:
System.getProperty("jetty.home");
System.getProperty("jetty.base");

Comment: The variable `{jetty.base}` is only present when running from `start.jar`.  If you are running using eclipse, then you don't have that variable.  Whatever plugin in eclipse you are using will have its own variables. (Note: there is **no official Eclipse integration for Jetty**, all plugins and projects that provide this are 3rd party, and all behave differently)

Comment: Internally, Jetty will set the `{jetty.home}` environment variable.  This *might be* equivalent to what you want.  But that really depends on the eclipse plugin you are using.